# Codeigniter Setting rules for form_validation isn't working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to validate 2 fields here, the "title" and the "HTML" field.

I have this code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', $this->input->post('title'), 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('html', $data['html'], 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    echo 'Fail';
}else{
    echo 'Success';
}
die();
```

I can confirm that both variables are valid strings.

The function always returns false, even if both fields are valid. If I only set one rule for one field, then the function will return true if it is a success.

Could somebody please advise?

Many thanks indeed,

Peter

Comment: Can you show generated markup code?

Comment: what is `$data` and can you post your form here

Comment: $data is all the fields that have name="data[field_name]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of your validation rules should be the human readable name of the field, not the actual data. Consider the following code.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('html', 'HTML', 'required');
```

The first rule will check the POST variable `$_POST['title']` to ensure that it is set and is between 5 and 255 characters. If it fails these rules the name `Title` is used in the error message. The second rule will check the variable `$_POST['html']` to ensure that it is set and if it is not set will use the name `HTML` in the error message.

Take a look at the [CodeIgniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) for more specific implementation details.

Based on your code, it looks like you want to run some variables that are not part of the `$_POST` array through form validation. To do this you have two choices. First you can put all of the data you want to validate into an array and use `$this->form_validation->set_data($array)` to use that array instead of `$_POST`. Alternatively you can just add the fields you want to validate to `$_POST`.

`set_data()` example:

```
$formData = array('title' => $this->input->post('title'), 'html' => $data['html']);
$this->form_validation->set_data($formData);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('html', 'HTML', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    echo 'Fail';
}else{
    echo 'Success';
}
```

`$_POST` example:

```
$_POST['html'] = $data['html'];
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('html', 'HTML', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    echo 'Fail';
}else{
    echo 'Success';
}
```

Personally I recommend the `$_POST` method.

Comment: I think its not the problem second parameter is just used in displaying error for the field your field name and rules matters not the title

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense.  How can I use an array within the set_rules parameters? Is that possible?

Comment: @PeterStuart Updated my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, thats it.  A quick question,  is $_POST safe to use? Why do CI create a post object instead?

Comment: CI provides their own interface to $_POST because it allows them to implement other intermediate code, for example the optional XSS filter or non-existent key handling. However since it doesn't let you set $_POST values through that class you have to set them manually using the array.